# Alix Board write performance

Tags: debian, performance, embedded, storage

I have an [alix board](http://pcengines.ch/alix2d2.htm) on which I have installed [debian4alix](http://code.google.com/p/debian-for-alix/) (sqeeze). After using it for a while I noticed that the write performance of the board was pretty low.

I ran the following test:

```
dd count=100 bs=1M if=/dev/urandom of=/var/www/cgrid/test
```

This yielded the following:

```
100+0 records in
100+0 records out
104857600 bytes (105 MB) copied, 328.903 s, 319 kB/s
```

This is the same speed I get when running the test on the compact flash card that the OS is installed on or on a flash disk. I had tested the flash disk performance on a linux desktop PC and achieved speeds around 15.3 MB/s using the same tests.

My read speed on the alix board is around 9MB/s (tested with `hdparm -t`)

I would like to know if the slow write speeds I am receiving is a result of the operating system ( since it is not running directly off the compact flash card but off a ramdisk) or from the embedded hardware solution being really slow.

Comment: Wtf... Give me my board back!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am quite certain the board is slower then desktop in terms hardware. But urandom make it worse.

The board is using a 500MHz CPU vs 2-3GHz desktop CPU. With `if=/dev/urandom`, your test is more about how fast the system can handle `urandom`. You are comparing CPU performance, not I/O.

Additionally, if the board only have 256M of ram, the OS may start swapping when creating 100M ram disk file. If that happen, it will have a big hit on test result. Maybe test with 50M file.

## Use if=/dev/zero

Don't use `if=/dev/urandom`. It is a very costly call for this test. Instead use `if=/dev/zero`.

## Test 1 - Write 100M to disk

Following is my test result from a virtual machine, also writing 100M.

### **if=/dev/zero**

```
john@U64D211:~$ time dd count=100 bs=1M if=/dev/zero of=test
100+0 records in
100+0 records out
104857600 bytes (105 MB) copied, 0.493612 s, 212 MB/s

real    0m0.540s
user    0m0.020s
sys 0m0.516s
```

### **if=/dev/urandom**

```
john@U64D211:~$ rm test
john@U64D211:~$ time dd count=100 bs=1M if=/dev/urandom of=test
100+0 records in
100+0 records out
104857600 bytes (105 MB) copied, 10.8723 s, 9.6 MB/s

real    0m10.909s
user    0m0.004s
sys 0m10.893s
john@U64D211:~$
```

## Test 2 - Write 100M to /dev/null

To show how costly is urandom, lets write to /dev/null, so no writing to disk.

### **if=/dev/zero**

```
john@U64D211:~$ time dd count=100 bs=1M if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null
100+0 records in
100+0 records out
104857600 bytes (105 MB) copied, 0.0240906 s, 4.4 GB/s

real    0m0.061s
user    0m0.012s
sys 0m0.052s
```

### **if=/dev/urandom**

```
john@U64D211:~$ time dd count=100 bs=1M if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/null
100+0 records in
100+0 records out
104857600 bytes (105 MB) copied, 10.4979 s, 10.0 MB/s

real    0m10.555s
user    0m0.024s
sys 0m10.513s
```

So when writing to `/dev/null`, almost 99% of time is spent by `urandom` system call.

**PS1**: VM has 4G of ram.

**PS2**: File caching do/may have affect the test result to some extend, but the difference between the `if` option is so huge that it is safe to ignore caching factor. And the effect should apply to both cases anyway.

**PS3**: I did not average out the test results. But I did run each multiple times with very similar result.

Comment: Thanks. You are correct, I got feedback from the maintainer of the OS who basically did the same thing as you. I didn't realize that a call to urandom was so expensive.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the result with `if=/dev/zero`?

Comment: I tested it by writing to the actual file system instead of /dev/null

`time dd count=100 bs=1M if=/dev/zero of=/test
100+0 records in
100+0 records out
104857600 bytes (105 MB) copied, 5.61246 s, 18.7 MB/s`

`real    0m5.620s
user    0m0.008s
sys     0m1.740s`